# not able to access graph.db in ubuntu

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, neo4j

My .db is shored in /home/gaurav/sharing/graph.db, when I try to access this directory using

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/home/gaurav/sharing/graph.db/"));
```

I get following error: (I'm not not eclipse as a root user)

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
>   /home/gaurav/sharing/graph.db     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:101)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$0(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   org.caleydo.neo4j.plugins.kshortestpaths.AppTest.run(AppTest.java:212)
>     at
>   org.caleydo.neo4j.plugins.kshortestpaths.AppTest.test0_2(AppTest.java:311)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)   at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)     at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:121)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@386112d6' was successfully
>   initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:189)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException:
>   Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable
>   automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter
>   "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"    at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:116)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.DatabaseMigrator.migrate(DatabaseMigrator.java:98)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:571)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:440)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
>     ... 30 more

Answer (score 0):

The last section of the stack trace says:

> Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable
>   automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter
>   "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"

You should either create a new datastore or set the above flag to true.

Comment: I have added this flag but still unable to read/ load graph.db from above location

Comment: @gaurav1207 is it still the same error? If so, could you please try move the database to a different place and see what the error becomes?

Comment: I moved the database to different place, but the problem is same. I'm able to create database but when I try to initiate my GraphDatabaseService instance, it is showing a null

Comment: @gaurav1207 just to check, did you put line "dbms.allow_format_migration=true" in conf/neo4j.conf?

Comment: @volantilervar yes that line was uncommented